# Select query syntax error multiple conductions

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM student_attendence WHERE Date = '06/Oct/2020' and St_id = 1 and = 2
```

I can't select multiple St_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare a column with multiple values you can use `IN` operator.

***Another Point***:
MySQL supported format date is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so before querying your database convert your input date to required format.

You can do that using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

If your database is storing `date` as varchar in same format as user input, you can skip this conversion.

```
SELECT * 
FROM student_attendence 
WHERE `Date` = STR_TO_DATE('06/Oct/2020','%d/%M/%Y')
    AND St_id IN (1, 2);
```